# example of embarcadero WindowHandleToPlatform c++

Tags: c++, c++builder

I need an example of WindowHandleToPlatform for c++ builder
I want to use the handle to do bitblt and other functions to a form
I can do this using VCL and works great.
Think WindowHandleToPlatform is the solution for firemonkey, but documentation is very poor

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the TPlatformServices? and that you want to get to IFMXWindowService?

Comment: No, I want to access The actual windows handle as the firemonkey handle does not support many things

Comment: Use WindowHandleToPlatform(Form1.Handle) will give you the actual Windows window handle.

Comment: @HuyPham: that would be `Form1->Handle` in C++. And if the calling code is already inside of the `TForm1` class, then drop the `Form1->` portion and access the `Handle` via the implicit `this` pointer (`Self` in Delphi).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <FMX.Platform.Win.hpp>

void __fastcall TMyForm::DoSomething()
{
    TWinWindowHandle *ThisHandle = WindowHandleToPlatform(this->Handle);
    if (ThisHandle != NULL)
    {
        HWND hWnd = ThisHandle->Wnd;
        if (ThisWnd != NULL)
        {
            // use ThisWnd as needed...
        }
    }
}
```

Or use `FormToHWND()` instead (which uses `WindowHandleToPlatform()` internally):

```
#include <FMX.Platform.Win.hpp>

void __fastcall TMyForm::DoSomething()
{
    HWND ThisWnd = FormToHWND(this);
    if (ThisWnd != NULL)
    {
        // use ThisWnd as needed...
    }
}
```

Either way, keep in mind that these functions are specific Windows.  If you want something that is cross-platform, you will have to find another solution.