# Detect screen lock - FMX in Win32

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I want my application to run some code when the screen gets locked (Win 7 and 10).  My application may be in the background too  when user locks screen.

Anyone point me in right direction?

Thank you,
relayman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`WTSRegisterSessionNotification()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsregistersessionnotification) to register an `HWND` to receive `WTS_SESSION_(UN)LOCK` notifications via the [`WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TermServ/wm-wtssession-change) window message.

You can use FMX's [`FormToHWND()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND) function to obtain your Form's `HWND`. However, FireMonkey controls, including Forms, do not have an overridable `WndProc()` method to process window messages, like VCL does, so you will have to use the Win32 API's `SetWindowLongPtr()` or `SetWindowSubclass()` function (see [Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/subclassing-overview) on MSDN) to receive the `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` window message:

```cpp
class TMyForm : public TForm
{
    ...
#ifdef _Windows
private:
    bool MonitoringWTS;
    static LRESULT CALLBACK SubclassWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);
protected:
    virtual void __fastcall CreateHandle();
#endif
    ...
};
```

```cpp
#ifdef _Windows

#include <FMX.Platform.Win.hpp>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <wtsapi32.h>

void __fastcall TMyForm::CreateHandle()
{
    MonitoringWTS = false;

    TForm::CreateHandle();

    // depending on which version of C++Builder you are using...
    HWND hWnd = FormToHWND(this);
    //HWND hWnd = WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle)->Wnd;
    //HWND hWnd = FmxHandleToHWND(Handle);

    if (!SetWindowSubclass(hWnd, &SubclassWndProc, 1, reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(this)))
        throw Exception(_D("Could not subclass window"));

    MonitoringWTS = WTSRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd, NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION);
    if (!MonitoringWTS)
        RaiseLastOSError();
}

LRESULT CALLBACK TMyForm::SubclassWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
        {
            WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd);
            reinterpret_cast<TMyForm*>(dwRefData)->MonitoringWTS = false;

            RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, &SubclassWndProc, uIdSubclass);
            break;
        }

        case WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE:
        {
            TMyForm *pThis = reinterpret_cast<TMyForm*>(dwRefData);

            switch (wParam)
            {
                case WTS_SESSION_LOCK:
                    // do something ...
                    break;

                case WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK:
                    // do something ...
                    break;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

#endif
```

Alternatively, you can use the RTL's [`AllocateHWnd()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.AllocateHWnd) function to create a hidden `HWND` and provide it with a custom `WndProc()` method:

```cpp
class TMyForm : public TForm
{
    ...
#ifdef _Windows
private:
    HWND WndForWTS;
    bool MonitoringWTS;
    void __fastcall WndProcForWTS(TMessage &Message);
public:
    __fastcall TMyForm(TComponent *Owner);
    __fastcall ~TMyForm();
#endif
    ...
};
```

```cpp
#ifdef _Windows

#include <wtsapi32.h>

__fastcall TMyForm::TMyForm(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    WndForWTS = AllocateHWnd(&WndProcForWTS);

    MonitoringWTS = WTSRegisterSessionNotification(WndForWTS, NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION);
    if (!MonitoringWTS)
    {
        int err = GetLastError();
        DeallocateHWnd(WndForWTS);
        RaiseLastOSError(err);
    }
}

__fastcall ~TMyForm();
{
    DeallocateHWnd(WndForWTS);
}

void __fastcall TMyForm::WndProcForWTS(TMessage &Message)
{
    switch (Message.Msg)
    {
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
        {
            if (MonitoringWTS)
            {
                WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification(WndForWTS);
                MonitoringWTS = false;
            }
            WndForWTS = NULL;
            break;
        }

        case WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE:
        {
            switch (Message.WParam)
            {
                case WTS_SESSION_LOCK:
                    // do something ...
                    break;

                case WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK:
                    // do something ...
                    break;
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    Message.Result = DefWindowProc(WndForWTS, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
}

#endif
```

Comment: I found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113627/example-of-embarcadero-windowhandletoplatform-c) but i don't know how to implement it.  I'm a toddler here.

Comment: Remy - are there examples you can point me to on how to do any of that?  I found this link (http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol2/9807/Message-handling_for_non-visual_components.htm) but i can't make it work in Tokyo 10.3.2.  I'm guessing it is too old/outdated and i don't know how to adapt it.

Comment: Remy, i created a new FMX project and i tried your first approach.  The first block i put in the Unit1.h and the second in the Unit1.cpp.  I changed TmyForm to TForm1.  When i run it i'm getting "E2268 Call to undefined function 'FormToHWND'.

Comment: @relayman357 which version of C++Builder are you using exactly? You never stated that. `FormToHWND()` requires XE5+, and is declared in `FMX.Platform.Win.hpp`. If your version does not have `FormToHWND() `, use `FmxHandleToHWND()` or `WindowHandleToPlatform()` instead. I updated my answer to show them

Comment: I have "C++Builder 10.2 Version 25.0.31059.3231" with installed update "10.2 Update 3".  What do you guys mean when you say XE5?   Thanks Remy!

Comment: @relayman357 `FormToHWND()` definitely exists in 10.2 Tokyo. Try fully qualifying its namespace (in case `DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE` is in effect): `HWND hWnd = Fmx::Platform::Win::FormToHWND(this);`  As for XE5, I am referring to C++Builder XE5, which is 6 versions before 10.2 Tokyo (XE5 was [released in 2013](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Release_Dates)).

Comment: That was it (needed to fully qualify namespace).  It works like a champ now!  Yes!!   Merry Christmas Remy!