# fire event after mouse moves form - FMX C++

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I want to run a block of code after my form has been moved on the screen by the traditional "left-mouse down on caption bar and drag to new spot".  OnMouseUp only works on the form itself, not for mouse click on the title bar.

This is C++ and Win32 app.

thanks,
russ

UPDATE 1:  Showing code i implemented based on Remy's answer.  I implemented his code from that other post and then added another item to the switch(uMsg) to catch the WM_MOVE message. This didn't work.

```
case WM_MOVE:
{
ShowMessage("Moved");
}
```

UPDATE 2:  I changed the above from `WM_MOVE` to `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` based on Remy's comment and it works great now.  Fires 1 time when i get through moving the form.

```
case WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
{
ShowMessage("Moved");
}
```

Just what i wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FireMonkey does not natively support what you are asking for. You will have to manually subclass the Form's HWND (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53578818/65863)) to intercept messages like [`WM_MOVING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-moving), [`WM_MOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-move), [`WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-entersizemove), [`WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-exitsizemove), etc.

Comment: I used the [reference you gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576639/detect-screen-lock-fmx-in-win32/53578818#53578818) and just added code for `WM_MOVE`.  It only fires 1 time when i start the application.  It never fires again when i move the form.  See my "UPDATE 1" code above.

Comment: @relayman357 what about WM_MOVING, WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE, and WM_EXITSIZEMOVE?

Comment: Awesome, `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` is the one to use.  It works and fires after i let go of the form (left mouse up) after dragging it by the caption bar.  This is exactly what i wanted.  Thank you sir!