# RestoreCapture FMX - Win32

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I took [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576639/detect-screen-lock-fmx-in-win32/53578818#53578818) of subclassing a Form's HWND as a starting point and then added in jrohde's code from [from here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/24514/) that is designed to let you drag a Form by clicking anywhere on it (not on the caption bar).  This code fails on the `ReleaseCapture()`line with this message: `E2283 Use . or -> to call '_fastcall TCommonCustomForm::ReleaseCapture()`

If i comment that line out the code runs and i can move the form by left mouse don and drag, but i can't let go of it.  The mouse gets stuck to the form like flypaper.  If i replace the `ReleaseCapture()` with a `ShowMessage` i can break out but that is obviously not the way to go...

What do i need to do allow that `RestoreCapture()` to run?  This is Win32 app.

BELOW IS THE CODE i added to [the original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576639/detect-screen-lock-fmx-in-win32/53578818#53578818) switch(uMsg) block:

```
    // two int's defined above the switch statement
    static int xClick;
    static int yClick;


    // new case added to the switch
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    SetCapture(hWnd);
    xClick = LOWORD(lParam);
    yClick = HIWORD(lParam);
    break;

    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    //ReleaseCapture();  // This is the problem spot <------------------------
    ShowMessage("Up");
    break;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
    if (GetCapture() == hWnd)  //Check if this window has mouse input
    {
    RECT rcWindow;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd,&rcWindow);
    int xMouse = LOWORD(lParam);
    int yMouse = HIWORD(lParam);
    int xWindow = rcWindow.left + xMouse - xClick;
    int yWindow = rcWindow.top + yMouse - yClick;
    SetWindowPos(hWnd,NULL,xWindow,yWindow,0,0,SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOZORDER);
    }
    break;
```

thanks, russ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message you can derive that the compiler resolves the function ReleaseCapture() to TCommonCustomForm::ReleaseCapture(). But you want to call the Win32 API function ReleaseCapture(). Use `::ReleaseCapture();` instead of `ReleaseCapture();` to enforce this.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you Klaus.  I had thought i needed a fully qualified namespace but i didn't know what it would be.  Is there some documentation that describes what that prefix :: is doing when used by itself up front like that?

Comment: :: without any identifier on the left refers to the global namespace.

Comment: And the Win32 API is a C-based API, not a C++-based API, so it does not use namespaces at all, everything is in the global namespace in C++.